# What could cause tpm_unsealdata to be unable to write to a file?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tpm

I have successfully sealed a file to the tpm after having taking ownership of it using `sudo tpm_sealdata -i inputfile -o encryptedfile -p 0 -p 1 -p 2 -p 3 -p 4 -p 5 -p 6 -z`, however upon attempting to run `sudo tpm_unsealdata -i encryptedfile -o newfile -z` I simply recieve an error of "Unable to write to output file" however, the new file has been created and is simply empty. what could be causing tpm_unsealdata to successfully create the file, but then fail to write to it?

Comment: If the file was empty, how could it have been encrypted? Also please provide the full commands you used if you want help. Run the command with strace to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a mistake withe my question, i meant to say the empty file was created but my mind was clearly not working right, the command to un-encrypt was failing after reating the file, Ill try using strace now, thanks.